# Category count but only if category has at least one post

Tags: categories, count

I need to display the number of categories which I can do with this...

```
<?php echo $num_cats  = wp_count_terms('category'); ?>
```

...but I only want it to count categories that have at least one post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
wp_count_terms( 'category', array( 'hide_empty' => TRUE ) );
```

You can check out the source [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1679).